# trouble with php password_verify

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm slowly working my way through the Lynda php mysql essentials course. I'm almost completely through, but it seems like the password will not verify.

```
<?php
require_once('../../private/initialize.php');

$errors = [];
$username = '';
$password = '';

if(is_post_request()) {

  $username = $_POST['username'] ?? '';
  $password = $_POST['password'] ?? '';

  // Validations
  if(is_blank($username)) {
    $errors[] = "Username cannot be blank.";
  }
  if(is_blank($password)) {
    $errors[] = "Password cannot be blank.";
  }

  // if there were no errors, try to login
  if(empty($errors)) {
    // Using one variable ensures that msg is the same
    $login_failure_msg = "Log in was unsuccessful.";

    $admin = find_admin_by_username($username);
    if($admin) {

      if(password_verify($password, $admin['hashed_password'])) {
        // password matches
        log_in_admin($admin);
        redirect_to(url_for('/staff/index.php'));
      } else {
        // username found, but password does not match
               //I output the password from the sql table just for debugging purposes                             
        $errors[] = $admin['hashed_password'];
      }

    } else {
      // no username found
      $errors[] = 'username';
    }

  }

}

?>
```

Here is the form

```
<?php $page_title = 'Log in'; ?>
<?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_header.php'); ?>

<div id="content">
  <h1>Log in</h1>

  <?php echo display_errors($errors); ?>

  <form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo h($username); ?>" /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />
  </form>

</div>

<?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_footer.php'); ?>
```

When I submit the form, I get an error about the password. I've spent a long time trying to figure this out and can't seem to find a solution. This is the first time I'm posting on stack overflow, so please let me know if there are any other code snippets I should have posted.

The error I receive is from the display errors function and it outputs the password from the table since I set $errors[] = $admin['hashed_password'];. I only did that to make sure I was using the correct password.

```
function display_errors($errors=array()) {
  $output = '';
  if(!empty($errors)) {
    $output .= "<div class=\"errors\">";
    $output .= "Please fix the following errors:";
    $output .= "<ul>";
    foreach($errors as $error) {
      $output .= "<li>" . h($error) . "</li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
    $output .= "</div>";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

find_admin_by_username

```
function find_admin_by_username($username) {
    global $db;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admins ";
    $sql .= "WHERE username='" . db_escape($db, $username) . "' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    confirm_result_set($result);
    $admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // find first
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return $admin; // returns an assoc. array
  }
```

Comment: Hey there! Something that would be helpful is the error you encountered when you "get an error about the password".

Comment: whats `find_admin_by_username` do\return

Comment: Below the line **$errors[] = $admin['hashed_password'];** add another one: **$errors[] = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);** change PASSWORD_DEFAULT for the algorithm you used to store the hash into database.